# What is the evolutionary purpose of citric acid?

Tags: evolution, botany, fruit, vegetable

According to Dr. Paul Saladin, fruits are brightly coloured and sweet because they want to be eaten to spread the seeds of the plant. Unlike roots stems seeds and leaves that don't. To deter consumption they produce chemicals that have extreme tastes like bitter or spicy (ginger, black pepper, chillis) etc. But lemons are brightly colored, however, they have their own extreme taste. What is actually the function of this?

And, come to think of it, chillis are often also brightly colored. What is the evolutionary function of that too?

Comment: Welcome Joe. This is not simply a Q&A site, here we are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on, see our section on [how to ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and see our [homework-question policy](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). Enjoy the Stackexchange network.

Comment: It’s worth remembering that many/most fruits have been selectively bred to taste a certain way by humans, so trying to infer evolutionary reasons may be hard.

Comment: Please consider that the question of how best to assure seed viability is not an either/or proposition. That’s a bifurcation. There are many ways to help seeds become seedlings besides color and taste of fruit.

Comment: As far as your question about chilis is concerned - bright colors in nature are also used as warnings. Look at the [various types](https://www.google.com/search?q=poison+dart+frog&tbm=isch) of [poison dart frogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_dart_frog), for example.